# Can SoapUI Project Files be Split?

Tags: soapui

Is it possible to split a SoapUI project XML file into many smaller files?

I can see the XML file being a contention point in code versioning, and result in many merge conflicts. It'd make more sense to have the project split into many smaller files so that changes are more isolated; but then we may end up with shared config being replicated between them.

Is the a commonly-adopted solution to this problem? I've never used SoapUI (someone on my team uses it) so I'm likely ignorant of SoapUI best practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

May be "composite project" option fits your requirements: http://www.soapui.org/Working-with-Projects/team-testing-support.html

This option is only available in soapUI Pro.

Answer (score 5):

To address this portion of the question:

> I can see the XML file being a contention point in code versioning, and result in many merge conflicts.

It may help to have SoapUI format the project file in a more VCS friendly way by pretty printing the project file. Try `Preferences -> WSDL Settings -> Pretty Print Project Files`

See also [Formatting a SoapUI Project File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135701/formatting-a-soapui-project-file)

Answer (score 2):

Here is small powershell script which parses requests from SoapUI project to separate files. It might be somehow useful.

```
$lookupPath = "C:\temp\soapui-project.xml"
$ouputFolder = "C:\temp\out"

$invalidChars = [io.path]::GetInvalidFileNamechars()

[xml] $contents = Get-Content $lookupPath

$ns = @{con="http://eviware.com/soapui/config"}
$items = Select-Xml -Xml $contents -XPath '//con:request[@mediaType="application/json"]'  -Namespace $ns
$nodes = $items | Foreach {$_.Node}

$requests = $nodes | 
    % {             
        $fileName = ($_.name -replace "[$invalidChars]","-") + ".txt"

        $_.request | out-file (join-path $ouputFolder $fileName)
    }
```