# Formatting a SoapUI Project File

Tags: soapui

I use the free edition of SoapUI (version 4.6.1) and notice that its project files are very poorly formatted.  Many of its elements are not on dedicated lines or indented like one would expect of a large XML file maintained by developers.

This makes it more difficult to diff & merge changes to source-controlled project files.

I am aware that SoapUI Pro offers a way to address this diff & merge difficulty with an option for multi-file composite projects as [another SO question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18508308/1810429) describe; but I would like to have a better experience with the free edition of SoapUI.

Is there a way to make SoapUI format its project files?

Comment: I don't think there is a way.  I would suggest formatting the file yourself before checking into source control.  You can probably find a simple utility to do this for you.  It's not ideal, but probably the best you can do with the free addition.

Comment: Adding to what EJK said, if it is xml you can format it with Notepad++ and the free xml plugin.

Comment: Those are great suggestions, EJK and Mike Cheel, were it not for there being an option to have SoapUI do the formatting directly per tdrury's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  Preferences -> WSDL Settings -> Pretty Print Project Files.

Comment: Thanks, tdrury.  I actually learned of this option just before asking the question...but wanted to make the Q&A easier for others to find since I only randomly learned of it after working with SoapUI for a while.