# Can we make SoapUI XML file diffable (git diff)

Tags: soapui

Assume I use soapUI for non-regression.
When doing a modify on a project it generates a XML file which is not made to be human readable.

This leads to some issues:

- it makes code review complex (`git diff` is not exploitable)
- can lead to conflict when several team members are working simultaneously.

I experience Karate: https://github.com/intuit/karate, which nicely solves the issue.

Is there ways/tips to avoid this issue when using SopaUI (file split, paid edition...) ?

Comment: Some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508308/can-soapui-project-files-be-split?rq=1 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135701/formatting-a-soapui-project-file

Comment: The paid version - ReadyAPI - solves this problem: https://www.soapui.org/docs/soapui-projects/team-testing-support/